# Visual Studio Code Git decorations disappear

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VSCode, and am really liking it. The Git integration on the Mac is really superb.

However, when I switched that project over to Linux, the Git decorators (indicating changed files) disappear from the File Explorer view. They still show up on the Git view in the left panel. Also, no indicators show up in the file editing window.

Looked online for help, which mainly says to turn on the option to show decorators ("git.decorators.enabled": true), which are on already.

Edit: if it matters, I'm using Mac 10.13.6 / VSC 1.28
Ubuntu 16.04 under Parallels / VSC 1.29.0
Ubuntu 18.04.1 under VirtualBox / VSC 1.28.2

Spent yesterday chasing this, and changing options, without success. I could just keep editing on Mac, and skip Linux, but with Linux improving every release, it'll only be a matter of time until I migrate...

Any suggestions on what I could do to bring those back on Linux? I'm pretty sure I saw them yesterday morning, then they went away as I did more stuff, and never came back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using symlink pointing to a folder? It appears that if I use the path of the symlink to a folder to open the project, the Git decorations would disappear from the File Explorer view, and if using the absolute path to that folder, then the Git decorations would appear.

Comment: Quick answer! And yes, I am using symlinks. Did a quick test, without links, and it worked right. I have a complex shared folder scenario, sharing my source folder between Mac & both Ubuntu's. Hadn't thought VSC would have problems with a symlink. Thanks for solution!!

Comment: You are more than welcome! Hope they can fix it someday.

Comment: Your a Lifesaver!

Comment: It's still valid 4 years later.

Comment: Thank you! After updating Dropbox, it moved the directory to a different path. I fixed it by reopening the directory using `File -> Open...`.